# SQl - How do I compare the data from one row to the next?

Tags: sql

My data has a single ticket record with a Slot field to identify how long the ticket will take.

I don't know how to have the empty date fields populate with the data above based on how many 30 min slots there in the ticket.

I want to replicate the SCHED_START AND SCHED_END dates from the ticket row to the other DATEDATE rows.

[image: Sample data snapshot]

Here's my query that produces this data:

> ```
> SELECT   DATEDATE
> ```

```
        ,TICKET_ID
        ,TECH
        ,TICK_TYPE
        ,SCHED_START
        ,SCHED_END
        ,PREV_DATE
        ,SLOTS
        ,SLOT_MINUTES
FROM DATES_TICKETS
ORDER BY DATEDATE, TECH
```

Comment: Take a look at analytic functions. It differs from db to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `last_value(ignore nulls)`:

```
select t.*,
       last_value(sched_start ignore nulls) over (order by datedate),
       . . .
from t;
```

Not all databases support this SQL standard functionality.

Comment: I want to populate the blank values with values from records with Non-Blank values.

Comment: Wow!  Gordon, I added this to my Oracle SQL query and it worked.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This is a great  solution!  Now I need to figure out how to stop the values when the number of SLOTS is reached